# How to control the space between the start of a bar and the axis in a bar-chart constructed using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am using d3.js library to construct a barchart with horizontal bars. When there are more than 50 bars in my chart then the spacing between the beginning of the axis and the first bar is strangely higher compared to when there are less than 50 total bars. 
**Spacing with less than 50 bars**  (desired behavior) - 
[image: **enter image description here**]

**Spacing with more than 50 bars** (undesirable) - 
[image]

I am wondering what could be the issue since in both the cases similar code flow is used. Is it even possible or is there any known attribute/property which is responsible for controlling this particular spacing ?

Comment: Can you share minimal code so that we can recreate the issue?

Comment: It will take me some time to get the minimal code which can recreate this. Meanwhile can you please confirm if there is any property/attribute which controls this offset/margin ?

Comment: If you are using a band scale, that would be normally set with [paddingOuter](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band_paddingOuter).

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to replace

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, size], 0.5);
```

with

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeBands([0, size], 0.5);
```

because using rangeRoundBand rounding apparently introduces additional outer padding which is, on average, proportional to the length of the domain. This is the reason why in case of more than 50 bars I was able to see more space at the beginning and the end.